# Python: how to faster approach to an unknown number given by a stochastic function

Tags: python

I have the following toy stochastic function:

```
def stochastic_func(param):
    result = param - 300 + int(np.random.randint(-20,21,1))
    return result
```

The goal is to guess a value for `param` that would make the `result` to be equal to, let's say, 500 (let's call it `target_val`). Obviously, you cannot guarantee that this value for `param` would always math the `target_val` due to the random term in the function. In fact, most of the time is not going to match. But you would need to hit the target **only once**. Of course, the uniform distribution here is just a toy example. In my real case scenario, the underlying distribution is completely unknown. What would be the faster way (i.e. less tries) to accomplish this purpose? My lazy stupid try:

```
param=1000
target_value=500
end_flag = False

while end_flag is not True:
    result = stochastic_func(param)
    if result == target_value:
        print("Winner param value: {}".format(param))
        break
    elif result > target_value:
        param = int(0.5*param)
    else:
        param += int(0.5*param)
```

Thx.

Comment: I am not sure if i get the question right, but if you know if your guess is bigger or smaller than the target value a fast way to find the number would be a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: @Finn This is useless here, as the number returned by the function is randomly chosen at each call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the stochastic function is a placeholder for some process of which you don't know the distribution. In that case it can be useful to incorporate the information of previous tries for `param` into the next try. You have already done this by looking at a single previous try, but you can take this a step further by looking at all previous tries.

In addition, in my answer I assume that by "faster" you mean in fewer tries, which is generally the goal if `stochastic_func` takes a while to evaluate.

I have a very simple example (definitely not optimized code) where I take a look at all previous attempts, select the maximum result that was lower than the target value and the minimum result that was larger than the target and take the mean of the two tries that lead to these results as the new attempt.

```
import numpy as np


def stochastic_func(param):
    result = param - 300 + int(np.random.randint(-20,21,1))
    return result


def new_param(tries, target_value):
    # Convert to a numpy array
    tries_mat = np.array(tries)
    
    # Sort the array based on the results column
    tries_mat = tries_mat[np.argsort(tries_mat[:, 1]), :]
    
    # Select indices of the results that are smaller than the target
    smaller = np.where(tries_mat[:, 1] < target_value)[0]
    
    # Select indices of the results that are larger than the target
    greater = np.where(tries_mat[:, 1] > target_value)[0]
    
    # The new guess will be the mean of the two that lead to the closest
    # approximations from below and above
    if len(smaller) > 0 and len(greater) > 0:
        lower = tries_mat[smaller.max(), 0]
        upper = tries_mat[greater.min(), 0]
        result = int((lower + upper) / 2)
    elif len(smaller) == 0:
        result = int(0.5 * tries_mat[0, 0])
    elif len(greater) == 0:
        result = int(1.5 * tries_mat[-1, 0])
    
    return result


def approximate_informed(param, target_value):
    end_flag = False
    
    count = 0
    tries = []
    
    while end_flag is not True:
        count += 1
        result = stochastic_func(param)
        
        if result == target_value:
            print("Winner param value: {}".format(param))
            break
        
        # Append the current try and its result to the list of tries
        tries.append([param, result])
        param = new_param(tries, target_value)
    
    return param, count
```

In combination with the following code

```
def approximate_simple(param, target_value):
    end_flag = False
    
    count = 0
    
    while end_flag is not True:
        count += 1
        result = stochastic_func(param)
        if result == target_value:
            print("Winner param value: {}".format(param))
            break
        elif result > target_value:
            param = int(0.5*param)
        else:
            param += int(0.5*param)
    
    return param, count


simple = []
informed = []

for _ in range(100):
    _, c1 = approximate_simple(1000, 500)
    _, c2 = approximate_informed(1000, 500)
    
    simple.append(c1)
    informed.append(c2)

print(np.array(simple).mean())
print(np.array(informed).mean())
```

I get an average of roughly 900 tries for your example implementation and 50 for the slightly more informed version. This problem is similar to hyperparameter tuning in machine learning, where methods such as Bayesian Optimization are used to make informed guesses for hyperparameters.

Comment: Yes, the stochastic function is just a placeholder for another algorithm of which I don't know the underlying distribution. And yep, by "faster" I mean fewer tries. So many thx!